# How can I configure the JDK for gradlew to use, on a per machine, per project basis?

Tags: java, git, gradle, gradlew

The projects in question are from multiple open source organisations, with multiple rules on their gitignores / build.gradle / gradle wrappers.

My default system wide JDK is set to Open Java 11. I'd like to keep it to the latest, released JDK.

How can I override individual projects gradle wrappers to use a specific JDK?; without

1. using command line arguments I won't be able to remember each time I need to invoke it.
2. changing the projects existing gitignores, gradle wrappers, or committed buildscripts/properties.
3. having changes needing to be ignored constantly in my local git repo.

Comment: Create a shell script on your `PATH` that looks where it's being invoked from, sets up the path to the correct JDK then invokes `gradlew`. Run the shell script instead of `gradlew`. Anything else is going to involve modifying gradle files in each project,

Comment: Thanks for the help @AndyBrown I still hope someone has a cleaner solution, but that will solve it for me. Please review my answer that I posted if you care to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.jenv.be/ is a tool that is literally made to solve problems like this.

What's jEnv ?

jEnv is a command line tool to help you forget how to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable

It can

- List managed JDKs
- Configure global version
- Configure local version (per directory)
- Configure shell instance version

Answer (score 0):

Create a file named `.gitignore_global` in your home directory, if it doesn't already exist (seems to be a common name online).

Add an entry that allows you to ignore a probably unused file extension for all projects.

```
#ignore all privignores
*.privignore
```

Run the following command, to add the global ignore file to your excludes git config.

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

Now any file in any git repo, ending with .privignore will be ignored by git.

create a bash script on your path, for me the relevant folder for user scripts was,

`~/.local/bin/` I named it `gradl`

```
#!/bin/bash
file=jdk.privignore
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
    export JAVA_HOME=`cat jdk.privignore`
fi 
echo $JAVA_HOME
exec ./gradlew "$@"
```

This script will set the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to the contents of `jdk.privignore` wherever `gradl` is invoked. This could be improved to only act, if the file exists. It will also pass through all arguments to `gradlew`

`chmod ~/.local/bin/gradl +x` will give the `gradl` script the execute bit so it can be run.

use `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to find what other possible Java's are installed.

one of the options will look like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java` you need to drop the `/jre/bin/java` from the end for JAVA_HOME

create a file in your gradle project root directory, next to `gradlew` called `jdk.privignore`

set it's content to: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`

Now when gradl is invoked, `JAVA_HOME` will be exported.